Scipy Fails to Install with PyPy, Linux
I'm trying to install scipy with pypy, version :
Python 3.8.13 (7.3.9+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1, Nov 15 2022, 06:22:50)
[PyPy 7.3.9 with GCC 11.3.0]


I've done a fresh install of pypy (sudo apt install pypy3) and gfortran (sudo apt install gfortran). I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.
However, when running pypy -m pip install scipy I'm getting this error,
where the failure occurs somewhere around here:
      [263/1619] Generating scipy/special/_data_gsl with a custom command
      FAILED: scipy/special/gsl.npz
      /usr2/repositories/DSP/dspos/RoomResponseRef/source/python/some_env/bin/pypy3 ../../scipy/special/utils/makenpz.py --use-timestamp gsl -o scipy/special
      Segmentation fault (core dumped)
      [264/1619] Compiling C++ object scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.pypy38-pp73-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/ellint_carlson_wrap.cxx.o
      [265/1619] Generating scipy/special/_data_boost with a custom command
      FAILED: scipy/special/boost.npz
      /usr2/repositories/DSP/dspos/RoomResponseRef/source/python/some_env/bin/pypy3 ../../scipy/special/utils/makenpz.py --use-timestamp boost -o scipy/special
      Segmentation fault (core dumped)
      [266/1619] Generating scipy/linalg/flinalg_module with a custom command
      [267/1619] Generating scipy/special/_data_local with a custom command
      FAILED: scipy/special/local.npz
      /usr2/repositories/DSP/dspos/RoomResponseRef/source/python/some_env/bin/pypy3 ../../scipy/special/utils/makenpz.py --use-timestamp local -o scipy/special
      Segmentation fault (core dumped)
      [268/1619] Generating 'scipy/special/_comb.pypy38-pp73-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/_comb.c'
      [269/1619] Generating 'scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.pypy38-pp73-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/_ccallback_c.c'
      [270/1619] Generating 'scipy/_lib/messagestream.pypy38-pp73-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/messagestream.c'
      [271/1619] Generating scipy/linalg/interpolative_module with a custom command
      [272/1619] Compiling Fortran object scipy/special/libspecfun.a.p/specfun_specfun.f.o
      [273/1619] Generating 'scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.pypy38-pp73-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/_ufuncs_cxx.cpp'
      [274/1619] Generating scipy/linalg/fblas_module with a custom command
      [275/1619] Generating 'scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.pypy38-pp73-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/_ellip_harm_2.c'
      [276/1619] Generating 'scipy/special/_test_internal.pypy38-pp73-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/_test_internal.c'
      [277/1619] Generating 'scipy/stats/_sobol.pypy38-pp73-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/_sobol.c'
      [278/1619] Generating scipy/linalg/flapack_module with a custom command
      [279/1619] Generating 'scipy/special/_ufuncs.pypy38-pp73-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/_ufuncs.c'
      [280/1619] Generating 'scipy/special/cython_special.pypy38-pp73-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/cython_special.c'
      ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
      INFO: autodetecting backend as ninja
      INFO: calculating backend command to run: /usr/bin/ninja
      + meson setup --prefix=/usr /tmp/pip-install-ecigaz4z/scipy_bae3c05728ed48d0a94e36cf7aeb04ac /tmp/pip-install-ecigaz4z/scipy_bae3c05728ed48d0a94e36cf7aeb04ac/.mesonpy-hvxyf1qr/build --native-file=/tmp/pip-install-ecigaz4z/scipy_bae3c05728ed48d0a94e36cf7aeb04ac/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
      + meson compile
      [end of output]
 
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
 
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
 
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

Any ideas? I'm afraid I have no idea how to start debugging this... Thanks!

How did you install pypy and gfortran? How did you attempt to install SciPy? Can you include the error message in your question? (Otherwise it is not searchable for future users.)

This may be related to this SciPy build error, which was caused by a bug in PyPy, which was fixed in PyPy 7.3.11. PyPy issue - PyPy release notes

It looks like this was a version issue, perhaps linked to Nick's comment.
After downloading the prebuilt latest version of pypy for Linux manually, following the instruction here, and explicitly running pypy3.10, installing scipy worked.
